# Android PermissionsDispatcher with API < 23

Tags: java, android, permissions

I use hotchemi PermissionsDispatcher to check permissions. It works perfectly for API >= 23. But I'm getting a FATAL EXCEPTION java.lang.StackOverflowError when I try to use the same code on a device with API 16. 
The error raise when I call `showCameraWithCheck()` in the generated class `MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher`

I went deeply into the class `MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher` generated by the PermissionsDispatcher library and found why the Stack Overflow happen. When I call `MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.showCameraWithCheck(this);` it goes to this method in the generated `MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher` :

```
static void showCameraWithCheck(MainActivity target) {
if (PermissionUtils.hasSelfPermissions(target, PERMISSION_SHOWCAMERA)) {
  target.showCamera();
} else {
  if (PermissionUtils.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(target, PERMISSION_SHOWCAMERA)) {
    target.showRationaleForCamera(new ShowCameraPermissionRequest(target));
  } else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(target, PERMISSION_SHOWCAMERA, REQUEST_SHOWCAMERA);
  }
}
```

}

The thing is `PermissionUtils.hasSelfPermissions(target, PERMISSION_SHOWCAMERA)` is always true so it called `target.showCamera()` which is my method who called `MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.showCameraWithCheck(this);` so it enter in a no end loop.... I guess the `hasSelfPermissions()` method check if it's runtime permissions (API >= 23) or old style permissions (< API 23).

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                               java.lang.StackOverflowError
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1376)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.checkPermission(ActivityManagerNative.java:2874)
>                                                                                                   at android.app.ContextImpl.checkPermission(ContextImpl.java:1285)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.checkPermission(ContextWrapper.java:421)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v4.content.PermissionChecker.checkPermission(PermissionChecker.java:89)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v4.content.PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(PermissionChecker.java:125)
>                                                                                                   at
>   permissions.dispatcher.PermissionUtils.hasSelfPermissions(PermissionUtils.java:73)
>                                                                                                   at
>   com.example.android.permissionsdispatcherapp.MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.showCameraWithCheck(MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.java:20)
>                                                                                                   at
>   com.example.android.permissionsdispatcherapp.MainActivity.showCamera(MainActivity.java:52)
>   ......................

```
@RuntimePermissions
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {

        Button btnShowCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_camera);
        btnShowCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Show camera button pressed.");
                showCamera();
            }

        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
void showCamera() {
    // NOTE: delegate the permission handling to generated method
    // ERROR
    MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.showCameraWithCheck(this);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    // NOTE: delegate the permission handling to generated method
    MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.onRequestPermissionsResult(this, requestCode, grantResults);
}

@OnPermissionDenied(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
void onCameraDenied() {
    // NOTE: Deal with a denied permission, e.g. by showing specific UI
    // or disabling certain functionality
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_camera_denied, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@OnNeverAskAgain(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
void onCameraNeverAskAgain() {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_camera_never_askagain, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@OnShowRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
void showRationaleForCamera(PermissionRequest request) {
    // NOTE: Show a rationale to explain why the permission is needed, e.g. with a dialog.
    // Call proceed() or cancel() on the provided PermissionRequest to continue or abort
    showRationaleDialog(R.string.permission_camera_rationale, request);
}

private void showRationaleDialog(@StringRes int messageResId, final PermissionRequest request) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_allow, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    request.proceed();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.button_deny, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    request.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage(messageResId)
            .show();
}
}

enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way. My code was wrong.
It doesn't need to call the `showCamera()` method because the generated class `MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher` already do it. As API 16 doesn't have runtime permissions it ends with this no end loop.

This is the fix :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
            Button btnShowCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_camera);
            btnShowCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Show camera button pressed.");
            askForPermission();
            }

        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void askForPermission() {
    MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.showCameraWithCheck(this);
}

@NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
void showCamera() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Showing camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```